# Suddenly getting NoSuchFieldError: usingExperimentalRuntime in App Engine with GCE libraries

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I just did a push (with no code changes) of my App Engine app, and it began throwing:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: usingExperimentalRuntime
at
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServicePb$MemcacheGetRequest.getSerializedSize (MemcacheServicePb.java:1597)
at
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.toByteArray (AbstractMessageLite.java:44)
at
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper.makeAsyncCall (MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:97)
at
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.doGet (AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:405)
at
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.get (AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:412)
at
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.get (MemcacheServiceImpl.java:49)
at
com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceImpl.getAccessToken (AppIdentityServiceImpl.java:288)
at
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential.intercept (AppIdentityCredential.java:98)
at
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper.intercept (AppIdentityCredential.java:243)
at
com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute (HttpRequest.java:868)
at
com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at
com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at
com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at
```

I am using version 1.9.80 of the following dependencies:

appengine-api-1.0-sdk
appengine-tools-sdk
appengine-maven-plugin

I have not changed the dependencies or code in any way since my last successful push several weeks ago.  I simply did a:

```
mvn clean install
mvn appengine:update
```

and it deployed successfully.

My service is dead in the water, as I don't seem to be able to roll back.

All the questions I've seen on this subject were from years ago, and they recommended going to version 1.9.49.  We're way past that now.  What magic do I need in order to get all my dependencies to stop looking for nonexistent fields in other dependencies?

Comment: What version were you using a couple weeks ago when the last push was sucessful? Make sure that you don't have any conflicting JARs from previous releases (1.9.80) and try again. Make sure that you check out the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/using-maven). Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I dug into it a bit and discovered that the errors stopped when I pushed from a different machine.  I must have a bad local build cache somewhere. You would think that mvn clean would delete everything. Still investigating.

Comment: Glad to hear! I thought I'd seen _java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: usingExperimentalRuntime_ before, and if my memory serves me right I think it was an issue related to having some conflicting JARs from previous versions. Let me post an answer in case somebody else is reading this, and you can judge if my answer is helpful or not.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, if you're noticing the following error message *java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: usingExperimentalRuntime*, and your dependencies were updated recently to a newer version, please make sure that you have all JARs updated to your current version and not previous versions.

For instance, mixing some JARs from version *1.9.78* and some others from version *1.9.80* can cause this issue. Therefore, you should move all your JARs to version *1.9.80*.